# Не могу найти шрифт Monospace Regular

Tags: linux, windows-10, шрифты

Не могу найти шрифт Monospace Regular. Такой же как установлен в Linux. Я сейчас на Windows 10. Когда сидел под линуксом мне очень нравился этот шрифт. Хочу такой же установить в Windows 10. Для редактора Geany. Все что качаю из интернета, или его вообще в шрифтах нет, или это совсем не то. Сидел на xfce вроде 4. Дистрибутив MX-Linux.[image: На всякий случай вот как он выглядит.]

Comment: Шрифта с таким названием не существует, так называется семейство шрифтов. А на скриншоте DejaVu Sans Mono или родственный ему

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, да, очень похоже на DejaVu Sans Mono. Буду пробовать установить

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо тебе огромное, человеческое. Сейчас установил в Visual Studio Code DejaVu Sans Mono. Выглядит так же как в Linux в Geany. Я очень доволен. Спасибо. Правда в Geany все же он отображается не так, но это уже вероятно проблема самого Geany под Windows. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть доступ к Linux-системе, найдите шрифт Monospace Regular.
Обычно шрифты в Linux находятся в каталоге  `/usr/share/fonts/`.Скопируйте файл шрифта (обычно с расширением `.ttf`).